# Permissions on files created by Linux in NTFS

Tags: linux, permissions, ntfs

I'm trying to mount NTFS filesystem in Linux with the following settings:

1. In Linux all files and directories in NTFS should be owned by `root`
   and have a group `win`. Permissions should be set to 775.
2. All files and directories created by Linux in NTFS filesystem should
   have in Windows the same ownership and permissions as a directory
   containing newly created file or directory.

To this end, I've added the following record to fstab:

```
/dev/sda7 /mnt/win/users_data ntfs-3g noauto,inherit,usermapping=/etc/ntfs-3g.usermapping,uid=0,gid=1002,umask=0002 0 0
```

Here is a content of the `/etc/ntfs-3g.usermapping` file:

```
:win:S-1-5-21-3452292639-2475245894-2622236828-1002
:win:S-1-5-21-3452292639-2475245894-2622236828-1003
:win:S-1-5-21-3452292639-2475245894-2622236828-1005
:win:S-1-5-21-3452292639-2475245894-2622236828-1004
:win:S-1-5-21-3452292639-2475245894-2622236828-1009
...
```

When the filesystem is mounted, the following message appears in console:

```
$ sudo mount /mnt/win/users_data
There were no valid user or no valid group
```

Files and directories in mounted filesystem have the right ownership and permissions in Linux (root:win 775). But in Windows all users is permitted to do all operations over files created by Linux in the filesystem.

What am I doing wrong? And how to mount NTFS filesystem in the way described above?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`mount.ntfs-3g` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g):

When a user mapping file (`usermapping=file-name`) is defined, the options `uid=`, `gid=`, `umask=`, `fmask=`, `dmask=` and `silent` are ignored.

> 1. In Linux all files and directories in NTFS should be owned by root and have a group win. Permissions should be set to 775.

You don't need a usermapping for this. Your UID, GID and umask settings are correct, just ditch the `usermapping=`

Point 2. is achieved by using `inherit` which you already have.

Comment: I've removed `usermapping` from the record in fstab. No more error messages appear in console when the filesystem being mounted. However, in Windows all users still have full rights over files created by Linux despite the presence of `inherit` option in the fstab record.